# Can't get rid of facebook desktop notifications from Chrome on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, google-chrome, mac, notifications

I have Chrome on Mac OSX.
When I get a facebook notification, I click on it, and on the page it displays, which is `https://www.facebook.com/...`, I click on the lock icon and it says *Notifications: Blocked by you* which I effectively blocked.
In settings I see it's added `https://www.facebook.com:443`, so I manually added all four combinations with and without `www.` and `:443`
But facebook notifications still show up.

Comment: system prefs > notifications. Is it disabled there?

Comment: I did it yesterday, haven't had notifications since, I'll watch it but maybe that did it.